# Why I am getting error for simple addition operation in Swift playground?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, swift-playground

I have very simple code,

```
var i = 1
var f = 10.34

println("i = \(i)") //fine
println("f = \(f)") //fine
println("i + f = \(i + f)")//error --> could not find member init
```

Now why I am getting error in last line? Am I not allowed to write expression with different data type in println?

Comment: What's the type of `i`?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Really sorry, my mistake.. it's 1, editing my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line `println("i + f = \(i + f)")` you are adding `Int` and `Double` which is not possible in swift.

You can convert `i` to double and your code will be:

```
println("i + f = \(Double(i) + f)")  // i + f = 11.34
```

Comment: Yes.. thanks. I will accept answer once SO removes restriction.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)